# How to merge data from mysql query coming from 2 databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can you help me with this? I am creating a data table from my web and it accessing 2 databases. All the tables from these databases are identical. But they have different data. Now in my webpage I have a datagrid. And I want to put all the product records in 1 table. But the table is composed of 2 databases.

The table I need to get the results is the `mtr_product_description`. And I have 2 databases named:

```
mtr_s7
mtr_s6
```

I have this code in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM mtr_s7.mtr_product_description AS apd 
LEFT JOIN mtr_s6.mtr_product_description AS bpd 
ON(apd.product_id = bpd.product_id);
```

And it display all the result. But it has a condition that should match it is the  product_id. How can I get all the records without using the condition?

Can you help me with this? 
Ok that's all. Thanks.

For sample illustration

```
DATABASE: mtr_s6
TABLE: mtr_product_description
DATA:
- APPLE
- BANANA
- ORANGE

DATABASE: mtr_s7
TABLE: mtr_product_description
DATA:
- APPLE
- MANGO

DESIRED OUTPUT
- APPLE
- BANANA
- ORANGE
- MANGO
```

Comment: Can you add sample data for a better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

If you need all data in 2 tables try below code:

```
SELECT * FROM mtr_s7.mtr_product_description AS apd 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM  mtr_s6.mtr_product_description AS bpd
```